# Set user description and job title during new mailbox creation

Tags: exchange-server

I am trying to create multiple linked mailboxes on Exchange 2013 using PowerShell and a .csv file. I have a column for each parameter I need in the .csv file.
The mailbox creation works fine with all parameters until I introduce "description" and "title". For some reason powershell does not recognize these parameters and the script fails. Here is the script I am using.

```
Import-Csv "C:\LinkedMailboxTest.csv" | foreach { New-Mailbox -Name $_.displayName -alias $_.Alias -FirstName $_.FirstName -Lastname $_.LastName -sAMAccountName $_.sAMAccountName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -description $_.description -title $_.title -Organizationalunit $_.OrganizationalUnit -LinkedMasterAccount $_.LinkedMasterAccount -LinkedDomainController $_.LinkedDomainController -Database $_.Database }
```

This is the error message I am getting: "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'description'. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Description and Title are not Exchange attributes, they are Active Directory attributes.  You will need to invoke a separate command **Set-user** to perform this.  Note in the linked materials that **Title** and **Description** are not available to set in the verb-Mailbox cmdlets.

[Set-Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123981(v=exchg.150).aspx)
[Set-User](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998221(v=exchg.150).aspx)